# Implementing combobox with command search

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

well i m having a problem when i use the method search i get only the textbox and not the combobox i m using mmvm here is my code:

in my constructor i have :

```
  CountryList = new FastObservableCollection<Country>(DummyWebservice.GetCountries());
     SearchCitizenCommand = new RelayCommand(SearchCitizen);
```

and for display countries and cities:

```
   private FastObservableCollection<City> citylist;
        public FastObservableCollection<City> CityList
        {
            get
            {
                return citylist;
            }
            set
            {
                Set(() => CityList, ref citylist, value);


            }
        }


        private FastObservableCollection<Country> countryList;
        public FastObservableCollection<Country> CountryList
        {
            get
            {
                return countryList;
            }
            set
            {
                Set(() => CountryList, ref countryList, value);

            }
        }
        private Country selectedcountry;
        public Country SelectedCountry
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedcountry;
            }

            set
            {
                Set(() => SelectedCountry, ref selectedcountry, value);
                OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedCity);
                CityList = DummyWebservice.GetCitiesByCountryId(SelectedCountry.Id);

            }
        }
        private City selectedcity;
        public City SelectedCity
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedcity;
            }

            set
            {
                Set(() => SelectedCity, ref selectedcity, value);



            }
        }
```

and finnally in the method search i tried

```
    SelectedCountry = new Country();
    SelectedCountry.Name = citizen.Citizenship.Name;
```

in the view i got :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="txtBirthCountryPicker"
                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding CountryList}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry}" />
```

but im still getting it umpty

Comment: If the problem is related to SelectedCountry, I can tell you which is the solution. If otherwise it's the CountryList, then there is something somewhere else...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select an item in a combo, you need to choose the exact same object that is part of the ItemsSource.

```
SelectedCountry = CountryList.FirstOrDefault(
   x => x.Name == citizen.Citizenship.Name
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Combobox uses object equality to determine which of item in the ItemsSource is the selected item. As you're assigning a new instance of Country to the SelectedItem, it is unable to locate the country in the ItemsSource.

Try this instead:

```
SelectedCountry = CountryList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name.Equals(citizen.Citizenship.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: the probleme is not with the data i already have an eventhandler sorry if i did nt put it with the code  i debugged and i got the data from citizen.Citizenship.Name the probleme is with selectedcountry the getter is not getting called again when it's set in the searchcommand

Comment: Does the ```Set(() => SelectedCountry, ref selectedcountry, value);``` emit a PropertyChanged event? I can only see that you're emitting a property changed event for the SelectedCity when the SelectedCountry is changed.